# How do I lump together all records that were inserted by the same query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that has a number identifying a group of values. This number increments each time an array of values are loaded into the database so this number will repeat for each value inserted at one given time.

How can I fetch this number and add 1 so that i can use a form to input new values with PHP?

If there is a better way of doing this I would be grateful to know.

Thanks

Comment: Are you just looking for an auto-incrementing column?  Or does the value repeat across multiple rows and increment per transactional insert rather than per record?

Comment: post your table schema, and some sample data

Comment: To expand on Dagon's comment, read ["Need an Answer? Actually, No ... You Need a Question"](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx) and ["Writing the Perfect Question"](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Answer (score 1):

Order your table descending by the incrementing column, and limit your result to only the first row. This will be the highest value.

```
SELECT incrementing_column 
FROM table 
ORDER BY incrementing_column DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you thats exactly what I meant. By the way, I know about normalization and by memory isn't one of the steps making sure that a column doesn't contain repeating values? how do you reference a group of subjects to another table by a value if you cant label them with the same value?

Comment: Consider what will happen if two users are doing this operation at the same time; there is nothing here that prevents them from getting the same value returned.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider concurrency issues. For example, when you have two users that are each adding a "new" array of numbers to the table, you probably don't want them to use the same sequence number. So you need to have some sort of "atomic" operation that prevents them from both returning the same sequence number.

(I'm going to assume here that an integer value is acceptable for a "sequence" number, absent any indication in your question that it isn't.)

One approach is to define a table with just a column with this "sequence" number in it, defined as AUTO_INCREMENT, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE seq (id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
```

Then, to get a "new" id number, you simply perform an INSERT into the table, and retrieve the auto generated id value. Your SQL statements might look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO seq (id) VALUES (NULL);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS id;
```

There are other (easier) ways to retrieve the value of LAST_INSERT_ID, but the particular method depends on whether you are using mysqli (mysqli_insert_id) or PDO (lastInsertId).

This approach is about the closest I've gotten (in MySQL) to an Oracle-style SEQUENCE object.

There are other approaches, but some are fundamentally broken (because they will possibly return duplicate values), and some have a negative impact on concurrency (because they lock tables to prevent concurrent retrieval and/or update.)

Answer (score -2):

You may want to look into the autoincrement feature of MySQL.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

This will allow you to identify a single ID field, that will be automatically incremented everytime a new record is entered without having to specify the value.